# VS2015-Cordova-Ionic-Angular-ngMap: map height defaults to 300px

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ng-map

I obviously have a lot to learn about CSS!

I'm using VS2015 and Cordova to develop a mobile application.  I'm using ngMap (http://ngmap.github.io/) to wrap Google maps.  I really like the library!  The problem is that it defaults the size of 300px, and my CSS skills are too poor to correctly override that.

I know that ngMap defaults to 300px, and that you can specify `default-style="false"` and then provide overrides in CSS that specify `position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%` - which should make the map fill the page.

When I try to do that, I end up with this: [image: utter failure]

When I accept the default behavior, I have a working map, but it's only 300px tall:
[image: I suck at CSS]

Here's a Plunker that's simple, but demonstrates the issue I'm experiencing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8qfGaLBMgXFtluELZhCs?p=preview

Note that the CSS has the recommended overrides.  When those are omitted, the map is visible - but only 300px tall.  I know this should not be so hard, and I know others have had success following the instructions listed above.  I just can't get it to work.

For what it's worth, the behavior is the same when I deploy it to my Samsung S5: I see the lower left-hand corner of the map.  Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some CSS and triggering "resize" event you can achieve your goal:

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.map {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.scroll {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
NgMap.getMap({ id: "splashSearch" }).then(function (map) {
  vm.map = map;

  $timeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
  }, 200);
});
```

Forked your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7dVCO8FpWxmLVVSMtqjH?p=preview

Comment: Thanks very much - that cleared it up!  Now I just need to find the right event to trigger that resize in the Ionic framework.  Your solution has me on the right track.  

I'm pragmatic and results-oriented... but if you could explain the 'why' behind this technique, I would appreciate it.  This seems rather arbitrary and capricious, like my first wife.